# Project Euler #8 in java

Tags: java, overflow, long-integer

The challenge is listed here:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> > > 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
> > >       96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
> > >       85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
> > >       12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
> > >       66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
> > >       62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
> > >       30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
> > >       70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
> > >       65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
> > >       52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
> > >       53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
> > >       83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
> > >       82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
> > >       16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
> > >       17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
> > >       24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
> > >       07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
> > >       84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
> > >       05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
> > >       71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

I have written a code that works with the given 4 digit example, but doesn't work for 13 digits. I suspect there is some type of data overflow, but I am unsure. My super inefficient code is below.

```
public class Euler8 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String num = "/*number listed above*/";
        int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, n12, n13;
        long sum=0, newSum;
        for(int n=0; n<=987; n++){
            n1=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n));
            n2=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+1));
            n3=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+2));
            n4=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+3));
            n5=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+4));
            n6=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+5));
            n7=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+6));
            n8=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+7));
            n9=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+8));
            n10=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+9));
            n11=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+10));
            n12=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+11));
            n13=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(n+12));
            newSum= (long)(n1*n2*n3*n4*n5*n6*n7*n8*n9*n10*n11*n12*n13);
            if(newSum>=sum)
                sum=newSum;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    } 
}
```

My code outputs this number:

```
2091059712
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes a cast to `long` too late: by the time the cast is performed, the multiplication has been completed in 32-bit integers, predictably causing an overflow.

Change the code as follows to fix the problem:

```
// newSum should be called newProd, because you use multiplication, not addition
newSum= ((long)n1)*n2*n3*n4*n5*n6*n7*n8*n9*n10*n11*n12*n13;
```

Note that your algorithm is not the most efficient: you could do it 13 times faster if you observe that the product for positions `i+1`..`i+13` can be computed from the product for positions `i`..`i+12` by dividing the value at position `i` and multiplying by the value at position `i+13`.

Of course you would have to be careful not to divide by zero. You can work around this by observing that any time you encounter a zero, the next 13 products would all be zero, so you could simply skip them, and move on to the next "train" of non-zeros.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation! I didn't know casting worked that way.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Thanks - I added a note to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `n1*n2*n3*n4*n5*n6*n7*n8*n9*n10*n11*n12*n13` overflows because:

- they are all `int` variables, and
- an `int` multiplied by an `int` gives an `int`.

The typecase to `long` is applied to the entire product, and (therefore) happens too late to cause the computations to be done with `long` arithmetic and avoid the overflow problem.

The simple solution to that particular problem is to declare the `n` variables as `long`.  It is possible that @dasblinkelights' code (casting `n1`) is faster ... but you would need to benchmark it to be sure.  And there are more significant optimizations than that.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer as 23514624000 . which is actually correct.

```
    public class LargestProduct {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
    String s="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    long k=0,l=13,ans=1,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n10,n11,n12,n13;
    long Max_Num=0;
    String[] result=new String[1000];
    result=s.split("");
    for(int i=0;i<=987;i++) {
        n1=Integer.parseInt(result[i]);
        n2=Integer.parseInt(result[i+1]);
        n3=Integer.parseInt(result[i+2]);
        n4=Integer.parseInt(result[i+3]);
        n5=Integer.parseInt(result[i+4]);
        n6=Integer.parseInt(result[i+5]);
        n7=Integer.parseInt(result[i+6]);
        n8=Integer.parseInt(result[i+7]);
        n9=Integer.parseInt(result[i+8]);
        n10=Integer.parseInt(result[i+9]);
        n11=Integer.parseInt(result[i+10]);
        n12=Integer.parseInt(result[i+11]);
        n13=Integer.parseInt(result[i+12]);
        ans=n1*n2*n3*n4*n5*n6*n7*n8*n9*n10*n11*n12*n13;
        Max_Num=Math.max(Max_Num, ans);
        }
    System.out.println(Max_Num);
    }
}
```